# Paginação, count para calcular de limit e offset pelo MYSQL

Tags: mysql

Tenho uma query com 7 relacionamentos em uma tabela relativamente grande, e a listagem dos registros usa como base o total de registros, então seria uma consulta para calcular o total e outro para exibir os registros entre o `limit` e `offset`.

Calculo do PHP para o `offset`...

```
$perpage = 10
$current = 1;
$records = 100; // select count()...
$average = ceil( $records / $perpage );
$offset  = ($current > $average) ? $perpage * ( $average - 1 ) : $perpage * ( $current - 1 );
```

Eu não conheço a fundo as operações do MYSQL, e somente encontro o total sendo feito via consulta.

Eu queria saber se existe alguma maneira de fazer o MYSQL fazer o calculo do `$offset` sem precisar executar uma query só para isso?

Comment: já há muito tempo que faço assim como tu, boa pergunta +1.

Comment: @JorgeB., Para as cositas pequenas nunca tive problema, mas rodar 2 querys praticamente idênticas e grandes, acredito que não seja a melhor opção. Quero otimizar isso, pois só de olhar me deu agonia :)

Comment: Acho que poderia trazer o total na mesma consulta usando uma subquery, mas além de ser meio estranho, não sei se traria alguma melhora no desempenho.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Andei procurando uma solução e encontrei `sql_calc_found_rows` e [`found_rows()`](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/information-functions.html#function_found-rows).

No exemplo que usei na questão, basicamente ele faz o calculo baseado no total de registros encontrados e valida a página corrente para ver se é maior que o total de páginas calculada. No entanto isso pode ser contornado usando o resultado de *found_rows()* posteriormente.

---

```
** QUERY 1
select sql_calc_found_rows id from TABELA limit ? offset ?
bindValue( $perpage )
bindValue( ( ( $current - 1 ) * $perpage ) )

** QUERY 2
select found_rows() as total
```

**Output**

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array( [id] => 4 )
    [1] => Array( [id] => 5 )
    [2] => Array( [id] => 6 )
)

Array
(
    [0] => 16
)
```

---

### Manual

```
mysql> SEELCT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS * FROM tbl_name
    -> WHERE id> 100 LIMIT 10; 
mysql> SEELCT FOUND_ROWS();
```

> 1) O segundo select retorna um número que indica quantas linhas o primeiro select teria retornado se tivesse sido escrito sem o LIMIT cláusula.
>
> 2) Se você estiver usando SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS, o MySQL deve calcular quantos registros existem no conjunto de resultados completo. No entanto, **isto é mais rápido do que a execução da consulta novamente sem LIMITE**, porque o conjunto de resultados não necessita de ser enviado para o cliente.
>
> 3) SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS e FOUND_ROWS() pode ser útil em situações em que você quer restringir o número de linhas que uma consulta retorna, mas também determinar o número de linhas no conjunto de resultados completo sem executar a consulta novamente. Um exemplo é um script da Web que apresenta um display paginado contendo links para as páginas que mostram outras seções de um resultado de pesquisa. Usando FOUND_ROWS() permite que você determine como muitas outras páginas são necessárias para o resto do resultado.