# Diferentes formas de contar números de registros no MySQL

Tags: php, mysql, sql

Exite diferença de performance se fizer:

```
//seleciona todos os itens da tabela
$cmd = "SELECT * FROM produtos";
$produtos = mysql_query($cmd);

//conta o total de itens
$total = mysql_num_rows($produtos);
```

ao invés de executar uma query: `SELECT count(*) FROM produtos`
para contar o numero de ocorrências no banco? OBS: desconsidere o uso do mysql/mysqli

Answer (score 19, accepted):

A técnica básica para contar registros é:

```
SELECT COUNT(*) FROM tabela
```

[Coloquei no **GitHub** para referência futura](https://github.com/maniero/SOpt/blob/master/SQL/Select/CountAll.sql).

Tem dois motivos:

- Isto trafegará apenas a contagem (uma única linha bem curta) e não todos os dados da tabela. Isto faz uma diferença enorme.
- E ainda ela é otimizada no MySQL. Ele não vai nem fazer nenhuma operação de contagem neste caso, ele pega o número do cache que ele já mantêm com esta informação.

Já fiz [uma pergunta](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/q/21583/101) sobre isto.

Comment: ,@bigown é possivel a sequinte sql? SELECT count(nome),durancao FROM produtos

Comment: Sim, é possível mas você perde boa parte da vantagem. Desta forma a contagem deverá ser feita e trafegará uma quantidade bem maior de dados que só a contagem . Mas se você precisa destes dados não há solução melhor. Mas esta já é um ganho em ralação a trazer tudo.

Comment: Uma forma que não sabia que funcionava mas parece que funciona, é `MAX(ROWNUM)`.

Comment: @GustavoCinque Não conheço bem a implementação disto, se pode haver *gap* entre números. Não sei se é confiável. Você tem alguma informação que mostre que é? Não para aceitar resultados que apenas são corretos por coincidência.

Comment: Não tenho, @bigown. Pelo que sei, o `ROWNUM` é a contagem de linhas do resultado, e com `MAX()` eu obtenho o maior valor das linhas. Vejo essa função sendo bastante utilizada por frameworks baseados em `jsf` (`richfaces` por exemplo), onde o maximo de resultado de uma grid é calculado dessa forma, e também é calculado o limite das paginas, utilizando-as em clausulas `WHERE`.

Comment: Estou procurando isto na documentação do MySQL e não estou achando nada, nem que existe isto. Embora eu entenda que se existir ele deva funcionar como você explicou. Só não sei se não há *gaps* na sequência que tornam o último número de linha o mesmo que a contagem de linhas.

Comment: Desculpe, confundi, rownum não é do MySQL. É [oracle](http://www.orafaq.com/wiki/ROWNUM).

Comment: Pelo que me parece, não há como reproduzir esse padrão em MySQL...

Answer (score 4):

Existe. Quando você executa o `SELECT * FROM produtos`, em termos de performance você precisa esperar o banco carregar todos os dados e entregar ao PHP. Então, o PHP fará a contagem de dados. Já o segundo caso `SELECT count(*) FROM produtos` o próprio banco lhe entrega somente a quantidade de dados existentes no banco. Muito mais eficiente em termos de contagem.

Answer (score 3):

Resposta baseada no comentário do Ricardo na resposta do Big. Se você quer retornar um limite de registros e saber o total como você usou: `SELECT count(nome),duracao FROM produtos`, como alternativa, acho que [**nessa questão**](https://pt.stackoverflow.com/a/46214/13412) você pode encontrar alguma ajuda.

```
mysql> SELECT SQL_CALC_FOUND_ROWS duracao FROM produtos LIMIT 10;
mysql> SELECT FOUND_ROWS();
```

O output será algo como o array abaixo - note que ele retorna o total de registros independentemente do *limit* informado na consulta:

```
Array(
    [0] => 50
    [1] => Array(
            [0] => Array( [duracao] => 1 )
            [1] => Array( [duracao] => 2 )
            ...
        )
)
```

Answer (score 2):

Com certeza. Imagine a memória utilizada para se obter 1000 produtos apenas para saber a quantidade. Executar um `count` irá retornar apenas um registro, representando uma grande melhora no consumo de memória.

Comment: O consumo da memória é um fator que ajuda a performance ser pior mas não é nem de longe o que mais a afeta.

Comment: Exatamente. 1000 produtos em comunicação... É melhor ir almoçar e voltar. Já agora dizer que Select * FRom deve de ser evitado sempre que possível.